# How to get composite component's child component's client ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, composite-component

I have a composite component with some parameters of input field IDs, such as:

```
<cc:attribute
    name="addressFieldId"
    required="true" />
```

I'd like to use the component like this:

```
<amn:singleLocationMap
    id="singleLocationMap"
    addressFieldId="address" .../>
<!-- some code, different ui:define regions -->
<h:inputText
    value=""
    id="address" />
```

But when I access the ID in JavaScript (`var address = '#{cc.attrs.addressFieldId}';`), I get only the id parameter `address`, obviously. But I'd like to access the JSF client ID like `formId:address`.

Is there any way to get the JSF client ID in JavaScript, or what is the best way to pass JSF client ID to composite component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `binding` to bind the component to an `UIComponent` variable in the view scope so that you can use [`UIComponent#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28%29) to print its actual client ID.

```
<h:inputText binding="#{addressInput}" ... />

...

<h:outputScript>
    var addressInput = document.getElementById('#{addressInput.clientId}');
    // ...
</h:outputScript>
```